# MacBook Pro Retina 2013 memory frequency limit

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I would like to replace the 2x8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 of soldered memory in my 15" 2013 MacBook Pro with some faster RAM. Is this MacBook Pro compatible?

---

This is not a duplicate question (Allan, patrix marked) because it about different device. Question about RAM frequency for specific device, not in general...

Comment: The device may be different, but the problem (using faster RAM) is the same.

Comment: omg, using faster RAM on Calculator is the same problem?... so many edits, duplicates, comments and ZERO useful information.. just delete this question and you will be satisfied!!

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure that the 2013 MBP will not be compatible with faster RAM than 1600MHz, Apple spec sheets state this, with a memory type of DDR3L.

DDR3 is capable of being faster than 1600MHz; DDR4 has different latencies and clockspeeds to DDR3.

I think you're on a hiding to nothing trying to de-solder DDR3 RAM and solder in DDR4. You can try if you like, but I suspect you will just end up with an expensive (but shiny) tray.

Comment: I didn't ask "is it possible" i already knew it. I asked about higher than 1600 MHz RAM support.

Comment: 16Gb is the max as well. So, you want to overclock it? Anyway, it is 1600. Again, according to a 2 minute google search.

Comment: @lan I want to replace 16GB 1600 MHz with 16GB 1600+ (DDR4 for example). "Anyway, it is 1600." - approve?

Comment: @Ian The edits made to the question no longer reflect the what is posted in the title.

Comment: @Allan Yeh sorry, I've tried to update the title, but the peer review failed.